# Notifying users with email when an event is created on the website

Tags: email, drupal

I have created a Drupal CCK content Event. When someone creates an event. I want an email to be sent to the users with one specific role. Also, this should happen if the creator of the event gives his consent to the website for this. How is this possible in Drupal website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module. It's made for things just like this.

Comment: Is there no other way to go about this?

Comment: You could custom code a less generic solution, fx in a submit hook for the node_form. But ultimately, there is only one way to do it, react on the content being created and execute a php function to send out the mails.